# Change location of zsh's process substitution ‘=()’

Tags: zsh, process-substitution

`zsh` is apparently using `/tmp/zshXXXXXX` to store temporary files created by the process substitution using `=()`. For example,

```
$ echo =(echo test)
/tmp/zsh4RmpQZ
```

However, I would like to change the location to `/run` to make use of my `tmpfs` mount.

Is there a configuration option in `zsh` to change the (default) location of the temporary file in the process substitution using `=()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zsh` shell uses the variable `TMPPREFIX` when creating temporary files.

According to the manual:

> `TMPPREFIX`

> A pathname prefix which the shell will use for all temporary
> files.  Note that this should include an initial part for the
> file name as well as any directory names.  The default is
> `/tmp/zsh`.

Testing:

```
% TMPPREFIX=$HOME/hello
% echo =(echo test)
/home/myself/hellotwu65k
```